# Computational Complexity of random Transverse-Ising Chain

Tags: complexity-theory, adiabatic-model

It is well known that many NP-hard classical problems can be mapped to a spin-configuration Ising problem (see for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.5843.pdf)

However, what I would like to know is what is the complexity of finding the ground state energy when extra transverse fields are added. For example, consider a $n$-qubit system interacting under the Hamiltonian:
\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{\langle i,j \rangle \in E} J_{ij} \sigma_i^z \sigma_j^z + \sum_{i=1}^n h_i \sigma_i^x
\end{equation}
where $E$ corresponds to the set of edges (i.e. whether node $i$ and $j$ are connected) and $J_{ij}$ and $h_i$ are coupling strength coefficients. More importantly, what I am mostly interested is what happens when the Hamiltonian above is restricted to nearest-neighbor interactions:

\begin{equation}
H = \sum_{i=1}^n J_{ij} \sigma_i^z \sigma_{i+1}^z + \sum_{i=1}^n h_i \sigma_i^x
\end{equation}

Is finding the ground state energy as *hard* as in a qubit-system where the connections are described by a graph $G$ (for example a 3-regular graph). Also, do we know if these random Transverse Ising Chains are gapped? For example can an Adiabatic Quantum Computer solve these kind of problems?

Comment: If your first Hamiltonian is on a 3-local graph, is your second Hamiltonian on a (two-local) cycle graph?